# Is there any Range Control in sap.m library?

Tags: sapui5

I am looking for a RangeSlider control in sap.m library. I found one in sap.ui.common but it's not working out in my case. Can anybody help me in finding control in sap.m library which is exactly like RangeSlider in sap.ui.commons?

Comment: Let us know, by clicking on the checkmark, if one of the answers was helpful. Read _[What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)_

Answer (score 1):

As of UI5 version 1.38, the [**`RangeSlider`** is available in the `sap.m` library](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/entity/sap.m.RangeSlider).

Here is an example with various settings:

```js
sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(() => sap.ui.require([
  "sap/ui/core/Fragment",
], async Fragment => {
  "use strict";

  const control = await Fragment.load({
    definition: `<RangeSlider xmlns="sap.m"
      min="-10"
      max="10"
      value="-4"
      value2="4"
      inputsAsTooltips="true"
      enableTickmarks="true"
      class="sapUiLargeMargin"
      width="33rem">
      <scale>
        <ResponsiveScale tickmarksBetweenLabels="5" />
      </scale>
    </RangeSlider>`,
  });
  control.placeAt("content");

}));
```

```html
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
  src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
  data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.core,sap.m"
  data-sap-ui-async="true"
  data-sap-ui-theme="sap_fiori_3"
  data-sap-ui-compatversion="edge"
  data-sap-ui-excludejquerycompat="true"
  data-sap-ui-xx-waitForTheme="init"
></script>
<body id="content" class="sapUiBody sapUiSizeCompact"></body>
```

Answer (score -1):

1.38+ SAPUI5 version RangeSlider from sap.m:

https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.44.18/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.RangeSlider/preview

Example:

```
<mvc:View
    controllerName="sap.m.sample.RangeSlider.RangeSlider"
    xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout"
    xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
    xmlns="sap.m">
        <RangeSlider range="20" min="0" max="100" width="80%"/>
</mvc:View>
```

in the range property you can bind the model